# What would be the correct translation for "United in Service: A council by, with, and for the people" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I have been taking up Latin for a few weeks now, however, I find Latin declension and noun cases to be quite challenging. May I ask for your help in properly translating the name above?

I currently have "servitio uniti: consilium [for, by, and with] populi."

Answer (score 5):

Ahem … what you have so far means “united in slavery”! (Or servitude.) That is presumably not what you have in mind.

For “service” (and I assume you are not talking about *military* service), [Smith & Hall](https://latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries/?t=sh22627) offer mostly *ministerium* and *opera*. That is OK for expressions like “services rendered” etc., but in this context I would suggest to use the gerund of *servire* (to serve), i.e. to translate, effectively, “united in serving.”

For “united” it is indeed tempting to use a form of *unitus* as you did, and certainly not wrong; however, it is not particularly idiomatic Latin. *Unire* is blue-moon level rare, *coniungere* is much more common, so I would recommend: **In serviendo coniuncti.**

*Consilium* for “council” is fine; I would prefer *concilium* (there are [a number of other choices](https://latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries/?t=do104)), because it seems less ambiguous (*consilium* can also be a plan, design, etc).

Now, “by, with, and for the people” is a very compact English formula that will be difficult to translate to similarly concise Latin. It evokes Abraham Lincoln's famous line from the [Gettysburg Address](https://www.abrahamlincolnonline.org/lincoln/speeches/gettysburg.htm) ([Powerpoint version](https://norvig.com/Gettysburg/index.htm)): “government of the people, by the people, for the people.” Interestingly that speech has been translated to Latin; [here is a translation](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3287681?seq=3) that says: *imperium populare, quod et a populo et pro populo administr[a]tur*. Maybe you agree with me that that is not very helpful for our purpose.

Instead I would choose to abandon all efforts at compactness and say: **concilium a populo creatum, cum populo inceptum, ad bonum populi peractum**, i.e. “a council created by the people, undertaken with the people, executed for the good of the people.”